# WPF ListView item selection unchecks checkbox

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, mvvm, checkbox

I have a this code:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="netcastListView" ItemsSource="{Binding NetcastList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Sync" />
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSynced}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModel}, Path=UpdateNetcastCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Netcast" />
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowTitle}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

When I select an item in the listview, it unchecks the checkbox which bleeds through to the binding.  How can I prevent this?

Edit / Clarification:
What I want to prevent is the checkbox from being affected when the item is selected.

Comment: What is the purpose of the command parameter?? Does the behavior change for the better if you take that out?

Comment: When the checkbox is checked/unchecked, it updates an xml configuration file and then kicks off some processes.  It passes along the "Netcast" object to the command. (the netcast I'm updating)

Comment: I left off something important.  I had a CommandBehaviorBinding that lets you assign a command to the selectionchanged event.  I took this off and it stopped unchecking the checkbox. I guess I have to find another way.

Comment: You can set the binding `OneWayToSource` if the intention is that it will only ever 'checked' by user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to modify the checkbox, then change the binding to `OneWay` and/or set `IsEnabled` on the checkbox to `False`

Comment: I do need to modify it.  That's why its a problem. If you'll notice, there is a command on the checkbox.